# Is it possible to avoid loop which will cast one object type to another in split() or Arrays.asList()?

Tags: java, arrays, type-conversion

I'm trying to simplify my code and I have a question: is it's possible to convert string of IDs separated by coma to specific collection type?

So, my code now is:

```
String [] condition_list_id_tmp = rule.getContractRuleConditions().split(",");
List<String> condition_list_id = Arrays.asList(condition_list_id_tmp);
List<Long> condition_ids = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for (String str_id : condition_list_id){
         condition_ids.add(Long.parseLong(str_id));
    }
```

Can I simplify this code by using for example `Type collectionType = new TypeToken<List<Long>>() {}.getType();` like in gson?

Comment: There is no alternative to the loop in the standard library. If you wait for Java 8, there probably **will** be an alternative there!

Comment: Side note: You can get rid of the condition_list_id and iterate over the array directly: `for(String str_id : condition_list_id_tmp) {`

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, the alternative probably would be only a syntax sugar, but at the end you need to read -> change -> write in cases like this or you expecting something else there ?

Comment: I'm surprised no one's mentioned [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/) see my answer... :-)

Comment: @Vash Yes, there will always be a loop somewhere down the line. But the full closures I have in mind transcend the level of mere syntactic sugar :)

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, for sure they do ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or using some libraries, like guava? so that there is no looping in your codes (but in theirs) ?
I saw that your mentioned your goal is "to simplify my code"

e.g.

```
final List<String> strList = Arrays.asList("1,2,3,4,5".split(","));
final List<Long> l = Lists.transform(strList, new Function<String, Long>() {
    @Override
    public Long apply(final String input) {
        return Long.parseLong(input);
    }
});
```

Comment: The code may not be simpler here if it is used just once, but if the Function is extracted and used multiple times, the savings and simplicity emerge through reuse.

Comment: Yes, like do it in two lines :)

Comment: Andriy, Java 8's closures **will** turn this into a one-liner. Something like (excuse my inaccuracy) `transform(strList, (String input) => parseLong(input));`.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered [LambdaJ](http://code.google.com/p/lambdaj/)?

```
class StringToLong implements Converter<String, Long> {
    public Long convert(String str) {
        return Long.parseLong(str);
    }
}

String [] condition_list_id_tmp = rule.getContractRuleConditions().split(",");
List<String> condition_list_id = Arrays.asList(condition_list_id_tmp);
List<Long> condition_ids = convert(condition_list_id, new StringToLong());
```

Comment: I have used LambdaJ for a while but, though the technique itself is fascinating, I finally dropped it. It only covers a union of special cases so each time you gotta wonder if your new need is covered by it and how. And please, did you see what Mario F. calls "closures"? It's ridiculous. The guy simply doesn't get the concept "close over local scope".

Answer (score 0):

I **don't** think so with out `looping` you can do this. How come your `collection's`  content type be changed with out casting explicitly .

Answer (score 0):

There is no method available without looping. Even if a method is available it will look like to you as a single operation but obviously it has to

> loop internally.

For eg: `Arrays.fill(arrayname, intval);`

This is a single method to fill the array with any integer value. But internally it will also run a loop on the array.

Comment: As I understood, it just will fill Long Array with same Long type value ?

Comment: No no! It can fill any type of array with same value of that type. For eg; It can fill boolean arrays with true or false, a long array with some long value etc. 

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

See the documentation here

Answer (score 0):

[java 8](http://jdk8.java.net/) can do this :

```
String [] condition_list_id_tmp = rule.getContractRuleConditions().split(",");
List<String> condition_list_id = Arrays.asList(condition_list_id_tmp);

List<Long> condition_ids = condition_list_id.map(c -> Long.parseLong(c))
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for your problem until Java 8 pop to the market could be project [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/Release13), with their support for [Functional Idioms](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/FunctionalExplained).

Then you could perform that operation in different way, but as i wrote in the comment. At the end you will have same operation.

```
public static List<Long> splitToLong(String list, String token) {

  StringTokenizer tokenizer= new StringTokenizer(list, token);
  List<Long> result = new ArrayList<Long>();
  while(tokenizer.hasMoreTokens() {
     result.add(Long.parseLong(tokenizer.nextToken()));
  }
}
```

If you put this method in some Util class, then you can enjoy clean code

```
 //....

 for(Long mLong : StringHelper.splitToLong(message,",")) {
    //Do something with mLong
 }

 //....
```